# Facebook Graph API not giving the name who makes a comment in page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Recently I tried to get the name who makes a comment in the post of my page using Facebook graph API. Everything is fine except the name who commented is not showing. I searched in stack overflow and find a answer where suggest to give the page access token. I gave the page access token but bad luck of mine. Graph API version is v3.1. IS there any solution?

Comment: Do you mean [first_name](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) and last_name?

Comment: whatever first_name or last_name or name.